# How to delete or unset a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, unset

I have a global variable in Javascript which is already populated by  previous function.

I know I can give this variable nonsense values to test but I think there is another way about it. For instance, I've put `some_var = undefined` and it works for the purpose of testing `typeof some_var == "undefined"`

Is there a more professional way of approaching this?

Comment: you can take any value which does not came from your function as indicator for a deleted value, but `undefined` or `null` may the way to go.

Comment: You *shouldn't* really be deleting variables. A variable should continue to exist as long as it's in scope, only its value should influence anything. Perhaps you should be restructuring your scope to get rid of the variable after you're done with it...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete window.some_var;` 
should do the trick.

Comment: not if some_var was declared with let or var first. If a variable was once declared with let or var *first* in your script you are stuck with it. Which, btw, is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Define your variables like this :

```
window.some_var = 1;
```

... or like this :

```
window["some_var"] = 1;
```

Then, you can delete them like this :

```
delete some_var;
```

... or like this :

```
delete window.some_var;
```

... or like this :

```
delete window["some_var"];
```

---

#### Note :

`delete` does **NOT** work if you define your variables like this :

```
var some_var = 1;
```

Comment: How to put this... err... No. That's *doesn't* actually work.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a global variable in Javascript which is already populated by
>   previous function

If it is global then

```
delete window["variable-name"]; //should do the trick

window.x = 1; //equivalent to var x = 1; if x is global
delete window.x;
```

if you have just the name of the global variable then

```
window["x"] = 1; //equivalent to var x = 1; if x is global
delete window.x
```